# I can't login into my account (arrays) in JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

So i want to create a program that creates a new account for the user, and the user should be able to 'login' with that same account. Now, i already managed to do the first part (create an account with arrays), but now i don't know how to login with that account.

PS: when i say login, it's just an alertbox that pops up

Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField ;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class LoginEN extends Application {

    Button btnCreate,btnLogin;
    TextField txtUsername;
    PasswordField Password;
    Label lblUsername,lblPassword;
    int index=0;
    String[] user = new String[11];
    String[] pas = new String[11];


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Create and login");


        btnCreate = new Button();
        btnCreate.setText("Create");

        btnLogin = new Button();
        btnLogin.setText("Login");

        txtUsername=new TextField();
        txtUsername.setMaxWidth(200);

        Password=new PasswordField();
        Password.setMaxWidth(200);

        lblUsername=new Label();
        lblUsername.setText("Username");

        lblPassword=new Label();
        lblPassword.setText("Pasword");

       btnCreate.setOnAction(e ->{
           if (index < 12){
            index++;  
            user[index]=txtUsername.getText();
            pas[index]=Password.getText();

           AlertBox.display("Account information","Your account has been succesfully created: \n Username: " + user[index] + " \n Pasword: " + pas[index]  );
           txtUsername.clear();
           Password.clear();
       }else{
           AlertBox.display("Error", "You reached the limit.");
       } 
       });
       btnLogin.setOnAction(e ->{
           for (int c = 0; c < 11; c++)
           {
                if ((txtUsername.equals(user[c])) && (Password.equals(user[c]))) {
                    AlertBox.display("OK", " Welcome to your account");
                }
                break;
        }
       });
        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(lblUsername,txtUsername,lblPassword,Password,btnCreate,btnLogin);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

Edited but still doesn't work :s ...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField ;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class LoginEN extends Application {

    Button btnCreate,btnLogin;
    TextField txtUsername;
    PasswordField Password;
    Label lblUsername,lblPassword;
    int index=0;
    String[] user = new String[11];
    String[] pas = new String[11];


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Create and login");


        btnCreate = new Button();
        btnCreate.setText("Create");

        btnLogin = new Button();
        btnLogin.setText("Login");

        txtUsername=new TextField();
        txtUsername.setMaxWidth(200);

        Password=new PasswordField();
        Password.setMaxWidth(200);

        lblUsername=new Label();
        lblUsername.setText("Username");

        lblPassword=new Label();
        lblPassword.setText("Pasword");

       btnCreate.setOnAction(e ->{
           if (index < 11){
           user[index]=txtUsername.getText();
           pas[index]=Password.getText();

           AlertBox.display("Account information","Your account has been succesfully created: \n Username: " + user[index] + " \n Pasword: " + pas[index]  );
           txtUsername.clear();
           Password.clear();
           index++;  
          }else{
           AlertBox.display("Error", "You reached the limit.");
          } 
       });
       btnLogin.setOnAction(e ->{
           for (int c = 0; c < 11; c++)
           {
                if ((txtUsername.equals(user[c])) && (Password.equals(pas[c]))) {
                    AlertBox.display("OK", " Welcome to your account");
                    break;
                }

        }
       });
        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(lblUsername,txtUsername,lblPassword,Password,btnCreate,btnLogin);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: wth do people downvote this post, it's just a question, i know it's a stupid one but at least help me instead of downvoting..

Comment: I want to point out that the reason this got downvoted (most likely) is because your question is a bit vague. It's not real clear as to what you mean by "i don't know how to login with that account."

Now to your problem; one thing I immediately notice is your index issues (still). If there's only suppose to be 11 users then the code that says:
if (index < 11) needs to be: if (index < 10) because if the index is 10 that means there is already 11 users (0 is counted). Your for loop is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
if (index < 12){
    index++;  
    user[index]=txtUsername.getText();
    pas[index]=Password.getText();

    AlertBox.display("Account information","Your account has been succesfully created: \n Username: " + user[index] + " \n Pasword: " + pas[index]  );
    txtUsername.clear();
    Password.clear();
}
```

your first account is created at `user[1]`, because you increment 'index' before you do

```
user[index]=txtUsername.getText();
pas[index]=Password.getText();
```

So, there doesnt' exists an user at `user[0]`, but in

```
for (int c = 0; c < 11; c++)
{
    if ((txtUsername.equals(user[c])) && (Password.equals(user[c]))) {
        AlertBox.display("OK", " Welcome to your account");
    }
    break;
 }
```

you start checking for users at index 0, and right after the if, you leave the loop with `break;`, so you never check for any user at index 1 to 10.
Also you compare `txtUsername` and `Password` with the Strings in the arrays, but `txtUsername` and `Password` are inputfields, which will never equal any String.

Also, your user- and password-arrays have length 11, so their highest index is 10. But at

```
if (index < 12)
```

you check for index lower than 12 AND increment it, so your used index could be 12, which result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, if you create more than 10 users.

To fix this, increment index after assignment

```
user[index]=txtUsername.getText();
pas[index]=Password.getText();
index++;
```

break inside the if and compare the text, not the fields itself

```
if ((txtUsername.getText().equals(user[c])) && (Password.getText().equals(user[c]))) {
    AlertBox.display("OK", " Welcome to your account");
    break;
}
```

and check for an index lower than 11

```
if (index < 11) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: As you can see above i edited my program, but it still doen't work tho :s i'm sorry it's probably a stupid thing again..

Comment: You compare `txtUsername` with `user[c]` and `Password` with `pas[c]`, 
The first ones are Inputfields, and the second ones are Strings, the they are never equal.
Just change `txtUsername.equals(..)` to `txtUsername.getText().equals(..)`
 and do the same with `Password`.